# how to display a set number of rows in a table view (titanium)

Tags: titanium-alloy

Manipulating the height like this is one way:

```
if(data.chats.length<8){
var newRowHeight = processBL.convert_percentage((data.chats.length*10)+5);
$.tableview.height = newRowHeight;

}
```

However it does not work if you have more than 10 rows. How can I specify how many rows I want on the tableview. Without setting it, I will typically have additional empty rows filling up the height of the table view.

Thanks

Comment: table view has automatic scroll in it, so if the rows go out of its height, scroll will come into action.
your question is not clear.

Comment: basically if I set the table view at height='100%' , there are a lot of empty rows. I just want to show the rows that are populated

Comment: you can set `separatorStyle :Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE` for table view it will hide the separator, and then you can customise the tableview row.

Comment: i tried this, seems to be a bug with the image view, if I click on the row after doing this, the view disappears for a second

Comment: found the bug, if you set the background Color on an element, it glitches. selectionStyle : 'Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE on createTableViewRow',
   solves it